# BufferedReader to ArrayList null

Tags: java, arraylist, null, filewriter, bufferedwriter

When trying to transfer data from a saved txt file to elements in an ArrayList, I'm running into a rather irritating null problem. It seems that when I use bufferedReader.readLine(), it erases the data in the txt file so that whenever I try to read the file again later in the program, it is just a series of null entries. I believe I need to read the file twice; once to find the number of lines in the txt file, and the second time to then use a for loop to transfer the lines from the txt file to the ArrayList. I've included the code below, so any help and insight would be greatly appreciated! Ultimately I just need to transfer all the data from this txt file to an arrayList...

```
    System.out.println("What is the name of the file you would like to open?");
    reader.nextLine();
    String name = reader.nextLine() + ".txt";
    System.out.println("Looking for file...");
    try {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(name);
      BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(fr);
      //Create a temporary ArrayList to store data
      ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

      //Find number of lines in txt file
      int numLine=0;
      String line = null;
      while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
        numLine++;
      }

      //write data from txt file to ArrayList temp
      for (int i = 0; i < numLine; i++) {
          temp.add(buf.readLine());
      }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("\n *********************");
  }
```

Comment: You've already read all the lines by the time you want to add stuff to the array list. Read the javadoc of `BufferedReader`. Why do you need to know the number of lines?

Comment: So you CAN only read it once? Yikes, I didn't know that. I didn't know how else to add the total txt file to an arrayList without knowing when to stop the loop (aka, the length of the txt data)

Comment: Why don't you use your `while` loop? It terminates correctly.

Comment: So just do: 
    while((line =buf.readLine()) != null) {
        temp.add(but.readLine);
    }
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Find number of lines in txt file
  int numLine=0;
  String line = null;
  while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    numLine++;
  }
```

You don't need the number of lines in the file. Remove all that.

```
  //write data from txt file to ArrayList temp
  for (int i = 0; i < numLine; i++) {
      temp.add(buf.readLine());
  }
```

Change that to

```
String line;
while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
{
    temp.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for spelling it out for me, I'm a student haha :) Works fine now